# Can we do Client side Encryption with Iceberg format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

currently we are working on AWS environment.
We are already having server side encryption on s3 bucket .
But in order to secure data in transit , we are planning to use Client side Encryption with s3 bucket dedicated for iceberg format .
Is there any way we can perform client side encryption with Iceberg format?

Comment: See https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/aws/